# Windows Batch File: usebackq, quotes within quotes

Tags: windows-xp, batch

Goal: Delete empty folders at end of a mutli-step clean-up. rd without "Force" removes directories that are not empty.

This works:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`"dir O:\Folder~1\Folder /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

These don't work:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`"dir \"O:\Folder With Spaces\Folder\" /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`"dir ""O:\Folder With Spaces\Folder"" /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`"dir ^"O:\Folder With Spaces\Folder^" /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

I know I'm missing something simple...

**EDIT**
Adding the example below to the mix:
[image]

If I actually echo the %d it echos.... "O:\Patient". Not the full name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the (outer) double quotes with `usebackq`.

You can get the list of directories from your piped commands, but when the output has spaces, only the first part will go to the `%%d` variable. To avoid that, use an additional `tokens=*` parameter (from `for /?`):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%d in (`dir "C:\Program Files" /ad /b /s ^| sort /R`) do echo "%%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipe character:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`dir /b ^| sort`) DO echo %i
```

Comment: Updated question with an example. The pipe isn't an issue (Actually removed it since the sort is kinda unneeded). The issue is the quotes within quotes.